# How can I obtain the cross loadings with lavaan?

Tags: r, r-lavaan

In my understanding, cross loadings can only be obtained from Structural Equation modeling (i.e. not from CFA) in lavaan. Am I correct?

How should I obtain the cross loadings with lavaan?

Code for reference:

```
model1 <- 'O  =~ o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + o5
T  =~  t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
G =~ g1 + g2 + g3
P =~ p1 + p2 + p3
P ~ OC + TC + TGC'

fit1 <- sem(model1, data=data)
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not mistaken

> model1 <- 'O  =~ o1 + o2 + o3 + o4 + o5 
>              T  =~  t1 + t2 + t3 + t4 
>              G  =~ g1 + g2 + g3
>              P  =~ p1 + p2 + p3'

Is the CFA, but if you want to build a SEM with lavaan, imagining you want to load O and T and G on P:

O + T + G ~ P

As they all are latent variable you cannot multiply them, but if you wish to do that anyway with an observable variable as moderator you can say:

O + T + MODERATOR_VAR ~ P , lavaan will calculate it automatically for you.

Now, if you want to force it anyways try O:T, but this is biased.